# Generic function specialization for a concrete type

Tags: generics, rust, traits, specialization

In [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3a0a556d7464d9815e1af7fdc20d5118) I'm trying to make some color conversion utils: I'd like to guarantee that every type that implements the `ColorSpace` trait can be easily converted to any other such type. To achieve this I ask to implement explicitly the functions `from_xyz` and `into_xyz` (since `XYZ` is the standard color space used in colorimetry) so that all other conversions (`from_color<T>` and `into_color<T>`) could use `XYZ` as an intermadiate step. In some cases this is redundant and more specific implementations are desirable: converting between a color space and `XYZ` or, for example, converting between `RGB` and `HSL` that derive directly from each other.
Is there a way to specialize a generic function implementation for a concrete type?

Comment: Specialization in Rust is unstable and partially unimplemented, so no, you cannot do that.

Comment: But if you insist, here's how you can do it on nightly: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ef9793d7cb433df0520fcd5f3160a00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html).

At the time of writing, it's [not stable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844), only available on nightly, and has multiple issues, so it's inadvisable to use it in its current form. Given the amount of time the issue has been open, it's unlikely to be stabilized anytime soon.